# Render html in-memory

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a NextJS server that returns some html, I want to `fetch` this html and render it in-memory so I can append it in the shadow-root of an element. The problem is that if I just do `innerHTML` the scripts are not executed, if I iterate over the script tags and manually re-create them inside the shadow-dom, NextJS is trying to query for `__NEXT_DATA__` but document.querySelector('#**NEXT_DATA**') is not finding the element since it lives inside the shadow-dom.

I am looking for a way to render the html in-memory without appending it to the actual DOM and once the rendering is done by NextJS to append the final result to the shadow-dom.

Imagine it as a micro-frontends architecture where various parts of the page belong to different NextJS applications. Any idea?